# Remove higher order derivatives from Maple expression

Tags: maple

Is there a simple way of only keeping (partial) derivatives up to some order in a Maple expression? For example, suppose I put

```
f(x) := (g(x)+diff(g(x),x))*(h(x)+diff(h(x),x))
```

The full expression for `f'` is

```
f'=g'h+gh'+2g'h'+gh''+g''h+g''h'+g'h''
```

and if I keep only the terms up to first order derivative I have

```
f'=g'h+gh'+2g'h'.
```

Is there a way in Maple to first do

```
diff(f(x),x)
```

and then remove by some command all derivatives of higher order than 1 (in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution involves converting to operator notation for the derivatives.

```
f := (g(x)+diff(g(x),x))*(h(x)+diff(h(x),x));
Df := convert( diff(f, x), D);
df := eval(Df,D@@2=0);
convert(df,diff);
```

The key here is that in operator form it is easy to get a hold of the second derivatives since they are acted on by the D@@2 operator.  If you replace that operator with the 0 operator, it maps all the second derivative terms to zero.  If you want to remove higher order terms, you have to do something like:

```
eval(Df,{seq(D@@i=0, i=2..5)});
```

If you want to do this with partial derivatives instead.

```
f := (g(x, y)+diff(g(x, y), x))*(h(x, y)+diff(h(x, y), x));
Df := convert(diff(f, x), D);
df := eval(Df, D[1, 1] = 0);
convert(df, diff);
```

In the context of partials, the differential operator is indexed with a sequence rather than composed.  So here, D[1,2] will be the partial wrt x followed by the partial wrt y.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to extend this to partial derivatives? I'm new to Maple so I'm sorry if the question is obvious.

Comment: Hi again! I have posted a question on Math SE where I elaborate on what it is I'm trying to do: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2208893/manipulation-of-partial-derivatives-in-maple

Comment: I added some notes on partials to this answer.  Hopefully enough to get you started.